# At a complete loss: mapping a simple entity via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't figure out why an object will not map via Annotations. No matter what I try, I always receive this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.hibernate.practice.Car
```

I was loosely following the tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-3-annotations) but can't seem to get anything working. I've tried to strip the object down to its bare bones (thinking that I was making an error in the code somewhere), but again, even with just an ID, and a name Column, I still fail to get this working.

My `hibernate.cfg` is from the Netbeans Hibernate tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practicedb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also, per the instructions, I've added the HibernateUtil.java class.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static {
    try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
      // config file.
      sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addPackage("com.hibernate.practice").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      // Log the exception. 
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

I set up a simple class. It's a `Car` with an ID and a Name.

```
@Entity
public class Car {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="incrememnt")
  private long id; 

  @Column(name="car_name")
  private String name; 

  public Car() {
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }





}
```

And finally, I'm trying to test this stuff out like this:

```
@Test
   public void testOutHibernate() {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Car car = new Car();
    car.setName("red one");
    session.save(car);


    try {
      Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
      session.save(car);
      t.commit();
    } 
    finally {
      session.close();
    }
    session.close();
   }
```

Without fail I get the `Unknown Entity Exception`. Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: You have a typo `strategy="incrememnt"` <-- spelled wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your annotated class as follows -

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                      .addAnnotatedClass(Car.class)
                      .addPackage("com.hibernate.practice")
                      .configure()
                      .buildSessionFactory();
```

---

You can find a discussion regarding the `addPackage()` method here - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=980723.